# Calculate end date based on start date and duration

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, date

I have Jquery date picker to select start date and dropdown to select number of weeks.

I'm using below codes to get the end date result but its not working:

```
    week_number_id.on('change', function(e) {
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();
    //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
    date_result_id.html('<i class="uk-icon-spinner uk-icon-spin"></i>');
    if (selectvalue == '') 
    {
        date_result_id.html(initial_date_result_html);
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            data:'option=com_mycom&task=getmydateHTML&dvalue='+selectvalue,
            success: function(output) {
                date_result_id.html(output);
                updateSelect(date_result_id.val());
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status +  ' ' + thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and on php code:

```
 public function getmydateHTML() {
     $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);         
     $dt = $jinput->get ('dvalue');
     $choosendate = $jinput->get ('start_date');       
     $newdate = strtotime("+". $dt . "week", $choosendate);
     echo   date('M d, Y', $newdate);     
    exit; // this will stop Joomla processing, and not output template modules etc.
}
```

Result calculating date starting from jan 01, 1970, weeks are increasing correctly but the code can not get the start date

Comment: what is the duration????

Comment: its based on number of weeks.

Comment: Here its works: [https://3v4l.org/UEYRv](https://3v4l.org/UEYRv)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `$choosendate` to timestamp. You need to create date from your date with valid format.

**See the example:** https://3v4l.org/SYltO

```
$week = "+1 weeks"; //"+". $dt . "week"
$str = 'jan 02, 2016';//$jinput->get('start_date')
$date = date_create($str);
$choosendate = date_format($date, "m/d/Y");    
$newdate = strtotime($week, strtotime($choosendate));
echo   date('M d, Y', $newdate);
```

Comment: Please check you have the correct date or not?? Check this `$choosendate`, If it is not maintain the date standard than you need to convert this first. But this is the process to do the work.

Comment: then how to convert start_date value?

Comment: Well If you can give me the value of `$choosendate` then i can give you the way.

Comment: May/02/2016 but preferring to have like May 02, 2016

Comment: Now its showing the date and calculating, but starting from today!, if i select  number of week 1 it shows Jun 02, 2016. not the one which selected from date picker (start_date) lets assume that i selected jan 01, 2016, so the result should be jan 08, 2016.

Comment: did you check everything?

Comment: yes, check my [link](http://blackdeers.net/project/pcp/reserve) press next, choose weekly then pick date and the from how many weeks dropdown select any number on left you can see the result date. the only thing here is the "start_date" id on my above codes replaced with "txtjQcal15_0"

Comment: Actually I think your script has some problem. See the example: [https://3v4l.org/SYltO](https://3v4l.org/SYltO), If you have the date like i use in the example.

Comment: The script dosent have any problem. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Welcome, Did you see the example i give last time?? If this is not gives smile in your face then i am sorry, i can't do any more for you.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. By the way the date time plugin which i used is [this](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) maybe you can take a look and find out any solution ...